# How do I test row by row error handling in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I am new to error handling in SSIS, I am wanting to know how to test it properly.  I found lots of examples of error handling for various transforms and sources complete with test cases, but want to know how to test error handling on a destination, specifically an OLE DB destination (SQL Server).

I'm trying to set up an SSIS package with error handling using a technique for fast load failing into row by row load like what is spelled out at the following link:  [Have your SSIS Fast Load (Bulk Load) and Row by Row Error Messages Too](https://www.anexinet.com/blog/have-your-ssis-fast-load-bulk-load-and-row-by-row-error-messages-too/)

I set it up just like they did.  I tried tweaking some data so that it would intentionally fail for testing purposes.  But of course it just failed on the source, so it didn't test my destinations.  So I'm wondering, how do I test the error handling I set up for the destinations, where it tries to fast load but falls back to row by row and then outputs the errant rows to a flat file?

Thank you in advance for any help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you trying to catch the error.
so there are several ways to achieve this, but for your scenario, you can use "Configure error output"
I will try to encapsulate you.

1. take the red arrow from your source and connect him with the "data reader destination".
2. when the "Configure error output" opened, go under "error" and "Truncation" and change to " redirect row".
3. right-click on the red arrow and choose "enable data viewer".
4. Run your package - when you run your package, a window will open with your error results.

[image]

example with error on the destination component:

[image]

Comment: That I am able to test just fine, it's the error output on the destination I am having trouble with.  I am not sure how to trigger an error so that I can test my destination error output.

Comment: Hi @Mike, you can double click on the destination component, then go to "error output", then continue from step 2 from the answer, is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: That's what I have done, but what I don't know how to do is test that error output.  I'd like to set up dummy data that will fail to the error output on the destination.

Comment: Create a source with a string column data type and destination with an int column data type, then map between them and run, and then it will fall. (I added a pic to the original answer)